# How to get n number of elements using xpath?

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am trying to get only 5 anchor elements using xpath.
Using something like

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a"));
```

gives me all the anchor elements.Is there anyway to get only a specific number of elements?

Comment: You can use `attribute-value` pair to distinguish anchor tags

Comment: Are you trying to find 5 specific A tags or the first 5 or any 5? Please clarify your question and post the code you have tried and the result, including any error messages.

Comment: i was looking for the first 5.

Answer (score 3):

Try below `XPath` to get just first 5 anchors:

```
"(//a)[position()<6]"
```

If you want elements from a specific range, e.g. anchors from 6 to 10:

```
"(//a)[position()>5 and position()<=10]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you do this

```
var elCount = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a")).count;
```

or it could be size if you're using java`

Answer (score 0):

You can use linq

```
var n = 5;
var list= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a")).Where(/*your condition here*/).Take(n)
```